# How to make a timer that in bukkit that's output is a variable

Tags: java, timer, bukkit

I am currently making a plugin for bukkit, and I was wondering if there is a way to make a timer that has an output as a variable. I want to make it a 5 minute timer and have it so that when a player runs a command, I says the time before the timer resets my current code is:

```
package com.agrocupcake.llamaenvoys.commands;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
int time = getServer().getScheduler() 300L;
var timer = time
public class EnvoyMain
implements CommandExecutor {
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String                    label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("envoy")) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("You must be a Player to preform this command");
            return false;
        }
        Player player = (Player)sender;
        sender.sendMessage((Object)ChatColor.GREEN + "Envoys Will drop in "+ timer + "seconds");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do, In java you can't type in variables before the class's scope.
Also you defined the variable player but you never used it.
And you can't intialize variable with VAR in java , Java is alot different than java script.
You should start the timer method in your onEnable() in your main class or whenever you want that timer to start counting down.

also note that if you reset the timer like the example i gave you the next down will start right after the time becomes 1, But if you cancel and return you will have to run the timer method again somewhere else to start the timer again.

```
package com.agrocupcake.llamaenvoys.commands;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class EnvoyMain
implements CommandExecutor {

private static int timer = 5;

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String                    label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("envoy")) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("You must be a Player to preform this command");
            return false;
        }
        Player player = (Player)sender;
        player.sendMessage((Object)ChatColor.GREEN + "Envoys Will drop in "+ timer + "seconds");
        }
        return false;
    }
}

//run this in your own enable or when you want your timer to start.
public static void timer(){
   new BukkitRunnable(){
     public void run(){
        timer -= 1
        if(timer == 0){
          //to reset the timer to 5 minutes
          timer = 5;
          //or to cancel the timer
          cancel();
          return;
        }
     }
   }
}.runTaskLater(<MainClass>.getPlugin(<MainClass>.class), 20*60)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your situation is create a `Timer class`. This is what your timer class should look like:

```
package yourPackage;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class Timer extends BukkitRunnable {

// This is the player that executed the command
private final Player player;

// These are the numbers that will be shown to the player when the timer
// reaches this number.
private final int[] mentionNumbers;

// The amount of minutes +1 because when the timer starts, it instantly
// removes 1 minute (due to the 'count--;' at the begin of the 'run' method.)
private int count = 6;

public Timer(Player player, int... mentionNumbers) {
    this.player = player;
    this.mentionNumbers = mentionNumbers;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    count--;
    if(count == 0){
        player.sendMessage("The timer has finished!");
        //Do whatever you want to do when the timer finishes.
        } else {
            for(int i : mentionNumbers){
                if(count == i){
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Envoys Will drop in " + i + "seconds");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you want to hook this in your command you can simply make a executor class like yours with a few modifications:

```
package yourPackage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class EnvoyCommand implements CommandExecutor {

// This maps contains all players and their timers
// This is to prevent players from running multiple timers at once.
private final Map<Player, Timer> timers = new HashMap<>();
private final Main main;

public EnvoyCommand(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if(!(sender instanceof Player)){
        sender.sendMessage("You must be a Player to preform this command");
        return true;
        // Make sure to return true here, because return false is only used
        // for an error in the usage of the command.
    }
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if(timers.containsKey(player)){
        player.sendMessage("The timer is already running!");
        return true;
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer(player, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
    timers.put(player, timer);

    timer.runTaskTimer(main, 0, 20 * 60); // 20*60 = 60 * 20 ticks or 60 seconds or 1 minute.
    return true;
    }
}
```

As I think you have already done, make sure to register your executor class in your `onEnable` method:

```
package test;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getCommand("envoy").setExecutor(new EnvoyCommand(this));
    }
}
```

And finally register the command in the `plugin.yml`:

```
name: yourPluginName
version: 1.0
main: yourPackage.yourMainClass
author: AgroCupcake

commands:
  envoy:
    description: Command description here
    usage: /envoy
```